# Why my jsp con't get the right data when using the jstl and spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, el

When I using the spring-mvc to give a model which name user from the database,and then,try to bind the data to jsp using the jstl tag ,it give me a error：

```
${userInfo..getName()}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${userInfo..getName()}]] with root cause
```

Data Bind Code:

```
User user = userService.getUserByAccount(account);
        if (checkUser(user) && checkUserLogin(user.getAccount(), session)) {
            model.addAttribute("userInfo", user);
        } else {
            return "redirect:/login.html";
        }
        return "user/userInfo";
```

jsp:

```
<h3> <c:out value="${userInfo.getName()}"></c:out>Welcome </h3>
<dl><dt> Phone </dt> <dd>
<c:out value="${userInfo.getPhone()}"></c:out></dd></dl>
```

Comment: Sorry to ask so stupid question.I have find my code error.The result is that I have using a ${userInfo..getName()} in my upper code.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is wrong (which is reported in stack trace). It contains two dots:

```
${userInfo..getName()}
```

try changing it to.

```
${userInfo.getName()}
```

Comment: I integrate this answer: in addition, you should refer properties instead of methods. If you want to retrieve the `name` value, do the following: `${userInfo.name}`

Answer (score 1):

Try using ${userInfo.name} and ${userInfo.phone}